# Как импортировать sql file в mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

Недавно перешел на Mac OS с windows. Толком не понял че да как пока-что, но решил использовать докер контейнеры mysql,nginx,phpmyadmin,php. Чтобы можно было уже работать. Mamp в бесплатной версии вроде не хранит логи отправки email, а мне они нужны, типо кому что отправлено. В общем решил контейнерами пользоваться. Все контейнеры успешно запустил. Базу создал. Данные читаются из тестовой базы. Теперь вопрос как импортировать sql файл в mysql. Файл базы данных большой, поэтому через phpMyAdmin импортировать не могу. Нужно ли для этого sql файл перенести в сам контейнер mysql? Или можно из главной машины(Mac OS) сразу импортировать в mysql который работает в контейнере? И какая для этого команда? Я пользовался этой `mysql -u root -p db_test < /Users/db_test.sql` ругается что нет такой директории. Хотя файл на маке в той директории точно лежит. То ли команда не правильная то ли файл должен быть в контейнере не понятно... Любые мысли, идеи будут в помощь как импортировать этот файл в mysql.

Comment: *Я пользовался этой `mysql -u root -p db_test < /Users/db_test.sql` ругается что нет такой директории.* Ясен пень, с точки зрения ОС в докере файл лежит в другом инстансе ОС - считай на другом компе. Потому тупо недоступен. Клиент командной строки `mysql` должен лежать на том компе, на котором находится файл, и оттуда запускаться, чтобы для него файл был "под боком". А MySQL для него будет соответственно на удалённом сервере, а не на локалхосте.

Comment: попробуйте через mysqlworkbench

Comment: @Akina так а что делать то щас? Надо получается файл sql как-то перенести в контейнер с mysql или как-то подругому?

Comment: Переместить файл в докер - это один из путей решения. Второй - запускать CLI не в докере, а в хостовой ОС (емнип это вполне самодостаточный модуль).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем. Сделал я общедоступную папку между главной машиной(хостом) Macbook и контейнером в котором работает Mysql. В файле docker-compose.yml там где прописан mysql добавил строку volumes где указал полный адрес папки на хосте и полный адрес папки на ОС контейнера mysql. Теперь все что кладу в ту папку доступно в контейнере и обратно это тоже работает.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.29
    container_name: docker-compose-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/custom-mysql-data
```